# Infopath with VS 2017?

Tags: development, infopath, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 and InfoPath 2013 installed currently and was investigating the custom code options for Infopath and it states that I need to install VS 2012. Is it possible to get Infopath to work with the newer version of VS or do I need to install 2012?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use "[XmlFormView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.server.controls.xmlformview.aspx)" class to embed the InfoPath form in a custom .aspx page. Then it's possible to access the values in the code behind using VS2017.

The XmlFormView object and its associated members are used to display InfoPath forms in a Web browser. No additional components are necessary on the desktop computer except a Web browser in order to open and fill out a form based on a browser-enabled form template.

InfoPath Forms Services uses the XmlFormView control to display forms based on form templates designed in Microsoft InfoPath so that they are browser-compatible.

EX:

In .aspx page

> ```
> <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
>     Namespace="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
> ```

```
<cc1:XmlFormView ID="XmlFormViewCtrl" runat="server" />
```

In code behind

```
//set the form URL
XmlFormViewCtrl.XsnLocation = "http://siteUrl/FormTemplates/Form1.xsn";

//Retrieve values
XPathNavigator myNav = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator field1= myNav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field1", this.NamespaceManager);
string fieldValue = field1.Value;
```